# Call bean property with a variable in property name

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, javabeans, el

I need to call a property like `${bean.data1A}`, but where the number in the property name is a variable. Something like `${bean.data{$n}A}`, but that evaluates to `${bean.data1A}` when n == 1. How can I achieve this?

I have a bunch of properties like:

```
${bean.data1A}
${bean.data2A}
${bean.data3A}
etc
```

Because I cannot call parameterized methods from a bean because of the old JSP Server I have to use.

---

**Update**: as to the reasoning for this, I have a grid of data (18 or 27 rows and 7 columns) that displays data from a bean. In this bean, there is a vector, where each element contains the an object that holds the data for the row (a, b, c, d, e, f, & g for a specific row can be retrieved using one element of the vector).

To use the grid, I can change as many cells as I want and then click an "update all" button. The reason I want to use ${n} as a variable for the row number is that the number of rows will changed based on the year of the data being shown. I'm currently using an ${n} variable to print the correct row number on the row labels for the grid

Comment: Isn't `f:setPropertyActionListener` available in the version you are using?

Comment: I'm calling a get method to retrieve a value, not a set method

Comment: Why don't you give us a more detailed description of you scenario. It can help a lot. I'm failing to see the need of sending the parameter to retrieve a value. If you need to send a parameter, than the `f:setPropertyActionListener` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I dont understand how that would help me, but let me explain my scenario better in an edit

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki Ideally I'd like to have a single bean method that would return the data I needed based on two parameters, row # and column letter. But because of my old .jsp version, I created a bunch of boilerplate methods like getData1A(), getData1B, etc etc

Comment: @Rodrigo: that's part of JSF which OP doesn't seem to be remotely familiar with. OP is asking this question in JSTL/EL context. Nothing in the question title, body or tags indicates JSF.

Comment: yeah, I'm not using a jspfragment, just a JSP page that uses JSTL/EL

Comment: @BalusC I see, I really didn't pay attention to that. My bad.

Comment: @user891242: JSF != JSPF. JSF (JavaServer Faces) is a component based MVC framework. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info The `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` is one of [the JSF tags](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/).

Comment: @BalusC, is there really no way for him to send the values to the server, so that he can avoid all the boilerplate code?

Comment: @Rod: Why? After all I guess you didn't understood the concrete question or perhaps even how basic JSP/EL works. JSP/EL just runs in the server, not in the client.

Comment: @BalusC: I did, I was just thinking of alternatives to solve his problem in a more organized fashion. Still getting used to Q&A format, so I'll stop littering the post here. Sorry and Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [EL's](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) brace notation `[]` to use a variable instead of a static string as property name. You can use [JSTL's](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:set>` to create a new variable in EL scope.

So, all with all, this should do:

```html
<c:set var="property" value="data${n}A" />
<c:out value="${bean[property]}" />
```